# How does Gmail automatically save your drafts while you’re writing?

Tags: html, websocket, gmail

In Gmail while you’re writing, it automatically saves your drafts.
How is this accomplished?

Is this with WebSocket? Is there any other feature with HTML5 to do so?

Comment: Maybe just with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail saves draft after you edit an email, I believe they do some kind of debouncing like you can do with [this](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) underscore function. I don't know their implementation details and how they send drafts to server, but this can be done with both WebSockets and with plain AJAX. To implement Gmail like draft saving you can use [Sisyphus.js library](http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/#customization) it will safe drafts locally using HTML5 LocalStorage but if you want to save them on a server you can customise it with [onSave, onBeforeRestore, onRestore and onRelease callbacks](http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/#customization)